# Why do all the cutters appear when I add a boolean modifier?

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image]

As the images below showed, every time I add a boolean, the cutters that I hid before appeared again while the blogger did this without the other cutters appeared.

[image]

[Tutorial](https://www.blenderbros.com/products/hard-surface-modeling-jumpstart/categories/2150162633/posts/2157168362)

Comment: pls add the link to the tutorial, thx

Comment: https://www.blenderbros.com/products/hard-surface-modeling-jumpstart/categories/2150162633/posts/2157168362
Here is the tutorial, but the cutting operation appeared many times in the video, and if you want to know the time of the step that showed in the image , please skip to the 01:50 of the chapter 03-- HS Modeling for beginners 03

Comment: I suspect it's because the viewport display setting for the cutter collection is enabled every time you add a cutter so making the bounding boxes of all the other cutters visible.